# Difficulty understanding Measure Proof

Tags: measure-theory

I'm reading through Bass' "Real Analysis for Graduate Students" and came across the following leap in a proof for a measure $\mu$.

Theorem: $\text { If } A_{i} \in \mathcal{A} \text { and } A=\cup_{i=1}^{\infty} A_{i}, \text { then } \mu(A) \leq \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \mu\left(A_{i}\right)$.

Beginning of proof: $\text { Let } B_{1}=A_{1}, B_{2}=A_{2}-A_{1}, B_{3}=A_{3}-\left(A_{1} \cup A_{2}\right), \dots$. The $B_i$ are pairwise disjoint, $B_{i} \subset A_{i} \text { for each } i, \cup_{i=1}^{n} B_{i}=\cup_{i=1}^{n} A_{i} \text { for each } n$ and $\cup_{i=1}^{\infty} B_{i}=\cup_{i=1}^{\infty} A_{i}$.

My question is - how does the author make the leap from showing $\cup A_i = \cup B_i$ for the finite $n$ case to the infinite case?

Answer (score 1):

By $B_i\subset A_i$, we know that $\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty B_i\subset\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i$. It then suffices to show that $\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i\subset\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty B_i$. Now, if $x\in\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i$, let $i^*$ be least such that $x\in A_{i^*}$ (exists by the well-ordering of the natural numbers). Then, $x\in A_{i^*}-\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^{i^*-1}A_i\right)=B_{i^*}\subset\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty B_i$.